# Entity Framework Core 8 Where IN vs Where IN OPENJSON

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2017, ef-core-8.0

EF Core 8 now inlines values in where statements using a combination of `WHERE IN` and `OPENJSON` as opposed to the previous `WHERE IN(...)`.

This change is [noted in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#queries-with-primitive-collections) and the stated reason is as follows:

> The inlining of values here is done in such a way that there is no
> chance of a SQL injection attack. The change to use JSON described
> below is all about performance, and nothing to do with security.

Unfortunately, `OPENJSON` performance on our 2017 SQL Server instance is poor.

The query below, generated by EF Core 8, takes **1.8 seconds** to run and results in nearly **400,000 reads**:

```
DECLARE @__scheduleTagIds_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'[5835,5970,6563,6564,6565,6645,6835,6850,7034,7127]';

SELECT  [s].[ScheduleTagId]
       ,[s].[MustStartProdBy]
FROM    [ScheduleTagMustStartBy] AS [s]
WHERE   [s].[ScheduleTagId] IN (
    SELECT  [s0].[value]
    FROM    OPENJSON(@__scheduleTagIds_0) WITH ([value] int '$') AS [s0]
)
```

If I refactor the query to use a standard `WHERE IN(...)`, the execution time drops to **120ms** and **29,000 reads**:

```
SELECT  [s].[ScheduleTagId]
       ,[s].[MustStartProdBy]
FROM    [ScheduleTagMustStartBy] AS [s]
WHERE   [s].[ScheduleTagId] IN (5835,5970,6563,6564,6565,6645,6835,6850,7034,7127)
```

I have hundreds of queries in my application that use `.Where(x => [collection].Contains(x.Id))` and I'm very concerned about the performance degradation I'm seeing in select queries.

**Question**

What can I do to to mitigate this issue? I'm open to options either in EF or on the SQL Server side (though don't want to change the compatibility level of the database).

Comment: SQL Server 2016 is out of mainstream support (even 2017 is), so the EF 8 team doesn't have to limit itself to only stuff that works fine with 2016

Comment: In my experience it's worth using it when you have large amounts of items. With these small amounts you better generate queries with chained "or" predicates. Ideally, EF would have some switch in their query translator that does that automatically, but it hasn't. All in all, I've experienced that it's a huge improvement with large amounts, performance-wise, but also because it prevents query plan pollution.

Comment: What's the patch level of the server?

Comment: I looked at the wrong SQL Server. This one is running 2017. I updated the question/tags to reflect that. I think the comments are still valid, however. Current version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB5029375)

Comment: Please share the execution plan for both slow and fast queries, please also show the tables and index definitions. I would imagine you would need an index `(ScheduleTagId) INCLUDE (MustStartProdBy)`

Comment: @Charlieface why would index requirements be different for the queries? They are both asking the same question, right?

Comment: I didn't say they would be different,, they probably are the same, but seeing the existing access patterns might inform us better. Eg query 1 might use a naive index scan with a nested loop against the JSON, and query 2 might use a hash join. Both are inefficient, but query 2 is much more inefficient. Point is: we need more info.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32394

Comment: So the problem is that `OPENJSON` gives a single execution plan that is used for any size collection but this has a fixed cardinality guess that it will emit 50 rows. Maybe they should have adopted Nick Craver's original suggested solution and just parameterise the actual values with variants for 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13617

Comment: We are seeing the exact same problem.  Updating to EF8 has caused signficant performance issues because of OpenJSON.   Yes, it saves the query plan, but the query itself has caused significant performance issues.   Wish this were an option, something like .ContainsWithOpenJson or .ContainsAsParameterized

We can't reverse compatibility mode for other reasons but we use .Contians a lot.  This is a big problem for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on the documentation, the only way to prevent the use of
> OPENJSON(... is to change the DB compatibility level to 120 (lower
> than SQL Server 2016). This is not an ideal solution. Is there any
> other way to limit/prevent the usage of OPENJSON?

You don't have to change the DB compatibility level to 120. You can call `UseCompatibilityLevel(120)` to tell EF to generate the old style SQL regardless of what the compat level is actually set to.

[There will also be an option to avoid this global setting and just constant-ize the specific queries that are problematic](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32394#issuecomment-1825513906). But I don't think this `EF.Constant` approach has made its way to the official release yet so you would need to use a daily build.

> Is there something configuration-wise on the SQL Server that would
> improve the performance of OPENJSON? It seems clear from the profiler
> data that SQL Server is not able to properly use index(es) when using
> OPENJSON.

It certainly can use indexes with `OPENJSON` it just might choose not to.

When you pass constants it can determine

- How many items are you passing?
- How many duplicates are you passing? If any?
- What are the exact values you are passing? (which may be useful if you have skewed cardinalities)

With `OPENJSON` it can't tell any of that so it just falls back to guesses. This may lead to a different (worse) plan.

Comment: Thanks for summing all of this up. I've been following the issue on github since someone shared it in a comment. Kind of a shocking regression from the EF team. I hope they deal with it quickly.

Comment: EF.Constant was already relased in EF Core 8.0.2.