With upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 8, facing performance issues
public async Task<List<object>> GetWorkareaEntityPeriodListAsync(List<Guid> entities)
{
    return await _dataBase.WorkareaEntityPeriods
        .Where(x => entities.Contains(x.WorkareaEntityPeriodId))
        .EntityProjectionGetDto()
        .Distinct()
        .ToListAsync();
}

public static IQueryable<object> EntityProjectionGetDto(this IQueryable<WorkareaEntityPeriod> workareaEntityPeriodQuery)
{
    return workareaEntityPeriodQuery.Select(s => new
    {
        Id = s.WorkareaEntityPeriodId,
        Name = s.WorkareaEntity.EntityName,
        ClientId = s.WorkareaEntity.ClientId,
        JurisdictionName = s.WorkareaEntity.JurisdictionName,
        JurisdictionId = s.WorkareaEntity.JurisdictionId,
        WorkArea = s.Workarea.WorkareaName,
        WorkareaId = s.Workarea.WorkareaId,
        WorkstreamName = s.WorkareaEntity.Workarea.Workstream,
        MarketOfferingId = s.WorkareaEntity.Workarea.MarketOfferingId,
        EngagementTypeId = s.WorkareaEntity.Workarea.EngagementTypeId,
        ProcessId = s.Workarea.ProcessId,
        ProjectId = s.WorkareaEntity.ProjectId,
        PeriodStart = s.PeriodStart,
        PeriodEnd = s.PeriodEnd,
        isOutscope = (bool?)s.EntitySettings.isOutscope,
        LinkedPeriodId = s.LinkedPeriodId,
        PriorPeriodId = s.PriorPeriodId,
        Region = s.Workarea.Region
    });
}

I upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8, and now it is not working, which earlier use to load very fast.
Issue is that it takes lot of time (gives upstream timeout) in .NET 8, while the same query returns in around 2 seconds.
The execution time has been drastically impacted, any suggestions?

Run SQL Server Profiler. Please share the trace of that query, both from .NET 6 and .NET 8.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77703991/5045688 - EF Core 8 uses OPENJSON. This can both improve and degrade performance. Try workaround with JOIN instead of Contains.

Another solution in that possibly duplicate question is to use EF.Constant(ids).Contains.

Why is Distinct used? That forces an extra sort in the database on columns that aren't covered by indexes. Isn't WorkareaEntityPeriodId the PK of  WorkareaEntityPeriods, thus preventing any duplicates?

I would suggest checking out ToQueryString to compare the differences between queries in .NET 6 and .NET 8.
Then compare the query execution plans by using something like SQL Management Studio (Depending on the database).
Check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750594/6866338 for more information, on how to set the CompatibilityLevel to change the way that EF Core generates it's queries.
Also maybe an interesting Github issue that might help: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32394
